# Can we please get a <ref>erence / [cite]ation feature?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, accessibility, citation, reference

Some stacks (or should I say: all scientific and linguistic ones) have extensive quotation needs, others do try to make people *back it up*, best with citations to authorities. Some Q&A might cite not just one but many sources or need to point to some 2 dozen parts of a text.

To denote citations, currently the only options seem to be:

- manual work with superscript and bibliography at the end (which is a MESS and takes hours)
- inline citations (which I find ugly)
- superscript-inline (a compromise of A & B which breaks accessibility)
- not quoting *at all*, which defies that we should quote, reducing the quality of the answers.

Can we get a neat `<ref></ref>`, [ref=...] or [cite=...] feature that auto-generates superscript numbers and puts whatever is between them after a line at the end of the text? This would guarantee accessibility and convenience at the same time.

---

#### Possible usage mockup

```
This is shown by Smith in his work[ref=Smith, John: Example Reference Work, p.17] and makes me think XYZ is a solution to the problem.
```

#### Result

This is shown by Smith in his work <sup>1</sup> and makes me think XYZ is a solution to the problem.

---

1. Smith, John: Example Reference Work, p.17

Comment: Right off the top of my head, just thinking about the stacks I'm either a member of or have visited because of interesting HNQs, I can see this being used in [english.se], [judaism.se], [ell.se], [law.se], [politics.se], [hermeneutics.se], and I wouldn't be surprised if it would also be useful in [christianity.se], [islam.se], [buddhism.se], [hinduism.se], and any of the language-specific stacks.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Add RPG (rules lawyering) and *any* language one.

Comment: @Trish - yep, thought of the language-specific stacks already; good catch on [rpg.se]. Probably also [boardgames.se], and a large number of others.

Comment: As `<ref>` looks like but is not HTML, it would bother me just a little. I could actually see this looking more like the SE "magic links"  but not actually linking, perhaps something like `[ref=Smith, John: Example Reference Work, p.17]`. But the functionality is definitely ***highly*** desirable.

Comment: Some of the stacks already have a Citation feature. Would this complement such a feature or partially replace it?

Comment: @Mast can you please point out which ones do? If it would replace them or just be one of those available to all might depend on the implementation.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Also the scientific stacks - I'm involved in Biology, Psych&Neuro, and Medical Sciences which all use citations extensively and effectively require them for nearly *every answer* (and most good questions as well), and I imagine other scientific stacks outside my bailiwick as well.

Comment: @Mast I think you are referring to the feature to generate a citation **to that SE post** (an extension of the "share" functionality in a format readable by citation managers), whereas this is asking about a tool to **add citations from a SE post to other sources**. In that sense, unless I'm missing something, it's orthogonal.

Comment: This has been suggested and shot down before: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116397/add-explicit-support-for-citing-scientific-literature but I think it's worthy of another look 5-10 years later.

Comment: I seriously doubt SE would make their implementation of commonmark even more personalized. They dropped the html tag for defining syntax highlight for code blocks in favor of something supported by the library.

Comment: @BryanKrause Oops, yes, you're correct. The feature I was thinking of is among-others on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), and works quite the other way around indeed.

Comment: Looks like [a userscript to help fulfill this need](https://stackapps.com/questions/6376/stack-exchange-references) was created some time ago over on StackApps, it's referenced in [an answer to the original Q](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116397/add-explicit-support-for-citing-scientific-literature/262187#262187) shared by BryanK above. No idea on whether it works today or not, but it's worth a mention.

Comment: Also related: [Make it easier to link to documentation for common technologies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/make-it-easier-to-link-to-documentation-for-common-technologies) | [Autocomplete/autoinsert links to API docs (or similar publically available docs)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126656/autocomplete-autoinsert-links-to-api-docs-or-similar-publically-available-docs)

Comment: Another possible option is to use [Kramdown's syntax for footnotes](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#footnotes), which I personally like a lot. Unfortunately, CommonMark doesn't seem to support this yet.

Comment: As I see it, the previous related questions were asking for the citations to be automatically generated from an external source, sometimes with links. While the links _would_ be nice - and perhaps the Wikipedia format/implementation for what amounts to this functionality might be worth looking at - I don't see this request as asking for the _linking_ functionality, just the generation of the footnote, as in the example that was edited in.

Comment: @hkotsubo There are extensions for CommonMark that adds the exact same thing from Kramdown (and many other Markdown flavors)

Comment: This citation style with superscript footnotes is extremely unusual in fields I am familiar with (mathematics, computer science). How would the citation feature cater for different citation styles?

Comment: It only needs to provide superscript and footnote, everything else is people writing "John Smith: Example Reference Work, p.17" or any other styling they need/want. It basically is meant to be an alternative to Inline-brackets.

Comment: @Trish But Emil's concern is that using a number linked to a footnote is not common in a lot of academic writing. Much formal citing is done in MLA or APA, which has inline citations like (Name, Year) and sorts the references section by name and year as well. A system entirely built around numbers would confuse some people or be of no use to them. And what happens if you need to use the same citation twice?

Comment: @animuson - There's  not going to be a one-size-fits-all solution to the problem, but what I might do in a stack that uses MLA/APA would be something along the line of "... blah (Smith, 1492)[ref=MLA-def-of-Smith-1492-here]..." the first time ONLY that any given reference is used, and then just use "...blah (Smith, 1492)..." subsequently. It's not perfect, in that the section at the end with the full cites is in the "wrong order", but it's still easier than hand-coding it all...

Comment: @hkotsubo - in addition to iBug's comment re: extensions, I'll also note that [Typora](https://typora.io) supports the Kramdown syntax for footnotes, though it's basing its implementation of Markdown on GFM rather than CommonMark.

Comment: @animuson the same citation twice actually isn't a problem, you can point to the very same item several times and still use running footnotes (as is usual in historical sciences in Germany) or *ibd* ("ebenda") for pointing out that the newly said is in exactly the same spot, but one could use a manual supertext. It'd still be faster than totally manual superscript & bibliography.

Comment: Note that Pandoc has a markdown extension that supports citing: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-citations

Answer (score -2):

### Which of the [myriad](https://www.scribbr.com/citing-sources/citation-styles/) of citation styles shall we implement?

You suggest superscript with footnotes - love it for Law SE, it's very close to OSCOLA (which, of course, has its own national variations); hate it for English and all the other language sites - they have to use MLA obviously.

History SE *has* to use Chicago A, Personal Finance *has* to use Harvard, Education *has* to use APA and Electrical Engineering *has* to use IEEE. You get the idea.

Unless we can get a consensus on the *right* way to cite (which has eluded academia for 500 years) we would have to implement all of them. This can be [done](https://endnote.com/), but its a complete business model distinct from Stack Exchange's.

Comment: Even though a different or customizable implementation for each site might be a nice bonus, I think any of the sites would settle for any style given that currently there is no implementation at all and references need to be formatted manually.

Comment: Usually individual academic journals have a house style, similarly each stack site might have it's own house style. There are libraries that can format citations in almost any imaginable style (see for instance https://github.com/jgm/citeproc). Also there is a specification for citation styles: https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html.

Comment: As suggested, I just want a tool that allows to format with footnotes - style is all manual.

Comment: “Unless we can get a consensus on the right way to cite we would have to implement all of them” — That’s clearly not true though: journals decide which citation style publications have to use. Stack Exchange could(/should) do the same (though given the prevalence of vastly different styles for different domains, it would almost certainly make sense to decide this on a per-site basis).

Comment: @Trish the point is that by using numerical, superscript footnotes you are _already_ imposing a particular style, regardless of how the text of the reference is formatted. Other people might prefer inline non-superscript numerical like `see also [1]` or author-year like `as shown by Smith (2010)`, which is not (trivially) possible with your proposal. However, as I said above I think most people would be happy with the implementation of this feature in any shape or form.